# Почему информация не выводится?

Tags: javascript, websocket

server:

```js
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

app.ws('/signin', function(ws, req) {
  ws.emit('message', 'hihihihihihihihi');
})
```

client:

```js
const signin = () => {
    const socket = io();

    socket.on('message', message => {
        console.log(message);
    })
}

signin();
```

Comment: Клиент создается после сервера и отправки сообщения.

Comment: `const socket = io('/signin');` Вроде так нужно на роут стучаться в этом вашем socket-io

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko, что тогда делать?

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Чтоб информация выводилась